# Controlling whitespace/newlines in XSLT output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been searching through the questions to see if this particular one's been answered with no success. If I simply missed it, my apologies.

I have the need to "flatten" individual XML nodes so that they are output as a single line. Whitespace between the nodes is not needed, and newlines within text nodes are tobe replaced by a special character ('\n').

An example XML:

```
<events>
  <event>
    <id>123</id>
    <type>read</type>
    <description>
      some text here
    </description>
  </event>
</events>
```

What I'd like as output is:

```
<events>
<event><id>123</id><type>read</type><description>\nsome text here\n</description></event>
</events>
```

I tried using the `<xsl:strip-space>` tag, and that takes care of the whitespace between the tags, but doesn't touch the newlines in side the  element.

I tried adding the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:copy-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;','\n')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but that seems to remove all the tags and just output the text.

Help?

Comment: The example XML, is that the input or the output?

Comment: The first listing is the input, the second the desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your sample XML input document:**

```
<events>
  <event>
    <id>123</id>
    <type>read</type>
    <description>
      some text here
    </description>
  </event>
</events>
```

**Given to this XSLT 2.0 transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[ \t\r]*\n[ \t\r]*', '\\n')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Produces your requested XML output document:**

```
<events><event><id>123</id><type>read</type><description>\nsome text here\n</description></event></events>
```